# Android XML enum name="center": aapt gives error 138 during "processDebugResources"

Tags: android, xml, enums, android-studio, aapt

I'm quite sure I've done it in the past, but creating an enum with the specific name "**center**", like this:

```
<declare-styleable name="Line">
    <attr name="foo">
        <enum name="center" value="0"/>
    </attr>
</declare-styleable>
```

Makes aapt throw the following error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':TestApp:processDebugResources'.
>
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>
> /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt package -f --no-crunch -I /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/platforms/android-19/android.jar -M /Users/eugeniomarletti/Dropbox/Projects/Test/build/manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml -S /Users/eugeniomarletti/Dropbox/Projects/Test/build/res/all/debug -A /Users/eugeniomarletti/Dropbox/Projects/Test/build/assets/debug -m -J /Users/eugeniomarletti/Dropbox/Projects/Test/build/source/r/debug -F /Users/eugeniomarletti/Dropbox/Projects/Test/build/libs/TestApp-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package com.test --output-text-symbols /Users/eugeniomarletti/Dropbox/Projects/Test/build/symbols/debug
>
> Error Code: 138

Anyone knows a solution to this?

Comment: What if you change "center" to "middle"?

Comment: That works, even using the name "Center" with the capital C works... Why THAT word specifically doesn't?!

Comment: I guess it's a reserved word, for Android?

Comment: Is there such a thing, in an enum? Besides there have been others doing it... Seems more like a bug!

Comment: Well, normally CONSTANTS in Java (and Enums are `collections of constants`) are written in ALL CAPITALS. This would avoid the issue.

Comment: But XML enums in Android are always lowercase...

Comment: Right, now I was forgetting the original question. I must have the memory of a red-fish: 5 seconds and reset. ;)